# Identifying wrongly used periods(.) from a text using python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to identify the incorrect use of periods(.) from the text using re.finditer. A period should always end with space is the condition. Using space before the period is incorrect to use.

in below code, I can able to find the periods in between the sentences. However, if it came at the end of all text it fails. Can anyone help to fix this?
[image: My try]

Comment: I guess there should be bunch of information to this. This might not be enough. what about `no.need to refer`?? is that period wrong? what about `98.56.78` are those wrong? is the first wrong? etc.. in the meantime, try can you try `\B\.`??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of examining the string around all of the periods, you could instead write a regular expression that finds "illegal" periods for you:

```
pat = "(?<=\s)\.|\.(?=[^\s])"  # A period with whitespace in front, 
                               # or a period with nonwhitespace after
any(re.finditer(pat, sample))

any(re.finditer(pat, "aab."))
# False
any(re.finditer(pat, "aab"))
# False
any(re.finditer(pat, "aab ."))
# True
any(re.finditer(pat, "aab.a"))
# True
```